# Difference between dauern and andauern based on an example

Tags: meaning, verb, verb-usage

I am trying to understand the difference between *"dauern"* and *"andauern"*. I checked lots of examples and stumbled upon one that I am not sure about.

Could you please explain me why, in this example, *"andauern"* is a better choice than *"dauern"*?

> Bis dahin wird diese Stagnation andauern.

Comment: "Andauern" points out that there is a (certain, limited) period of time where a certain state exists, focussing in the state. "Dauern" would refer more to the duration of this period. Like "Die Stagnation wird drei Jahre dauern." focuses on more the three years, whereas "The Stagnation wird drei Jahre andauern." focuses on more the stagnation.

Comment: @BogisW: Die Kommentare sind nicht für Antworten gedacht.

Comment: Du hast grundsätzlich Recht. Ich war beim Schreiben nicht sicher, ob das so stimmt - zu wenig sicher für eine Antwort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"[Ein Zustand] dauert an."* means *"[A state] continues (to exist)."*. A lower register term that means the same is: *"[Ein Zustand] geht weiter."*

> Die Stagnation dauert an.
> Die Stagnation geht weiter.
> *(Stagnation continues)*

It implies that the state is already ongoing.

*Dauern* means *to require*, *to take* or *to last* in the sense of

> Der Bau der Brücke dauert vier Monate. *(Building the bridge takes/requires four months.)* 
> Die Stagnation dauerte drei Jahre. *(Stagnation lasted for three years.)*

It looks at a duration as a whole. It does not have the sense of *to continue* that *andauern* has.

Note that you can still use "andauern" in the past, too:

> Die Stagnation dauerte über drei Jahre an.
> *(Stagnation continued for three years.)*

but, like in the English translation, it still has a slighly different perspective on the duration than "Die Stagnation dauerte drei Jahre.".